# GKE Ingress Bad Gateway or Backend not found

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm creating this issue though there are various answers available but couldn't answer my problem. I'm using GKE Ingress in my example.

I've been using GKE and setup GKE Ingress mere to manage the path for all which we have kept in GCR.
I've created a .net core based API which is has various path , if I expose the deployment with service as type Loadbalancer it works perfectly. Though when I utilize GKE Ingress and setup service and its backend it throws an error like Bad Gateway or sometime backend not found.

.Net core api application exposes following path when i exposed on service as ***loadbalancer***, kindly follow below screenshot for reference:
http://35.202.38.40/api/books

http://35.202.38.40/api/categories

[image: ![![image]]

The same way we do have other post api's.

Now I'm stuck when I utilize GKE ingress and setup my ingress.yaml as follows , it doesn't work and throws an error.
Ingress.Yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gke-ingress
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"      
spec:  
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*       
        backend:          
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /kube       
        backend:          
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes
          servicePort: 80
```

**NOTE**: my hello-word is exposing a .Net Core API application, kindly don't get confuse with name as "hello-world" for testing.

**Service Yaml**

```
  apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: hello-world
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      selector:
        greeting: hello
        department: world
      ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 80
        targetPort: 80
```

Deployment Yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      greeting: hello
      department: world
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        greeting: hello
        department: world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: gcr.io/gcpone-yuy-123114/oneplus2:631
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Kindly advise how to setup path based routing in GKE Ingress for .Net Core Api app

[image]

**NOTE**
Inside the bash shell of pod i tried to reach my api on localhost and it responded as shown below: What am i missing ???

[image]

Comment: First thing, it looks like you have indentation error in `paths` section of your `Ingress` definition. Second, are these 2 distinct service names in your original `Ingress` manifest or you are referring in both patsh to a single service name ?

Comment: Mario, I've updated an indentation ,also added new path for second service.The second service on this url http://34.117.45.162/kube always returns me response as expected the only problem is with the http://34.117.45.162/ this..it only throws internal server 502 error. My first service hello-world is a .net core api which doesn't return any thing.if i run at local host it opens up a following url https://localhost:55000/swagger/index.html and other api works fine at this path https://localhost:55000/api/Items, but GKE ingress is not able to rewrite such rule. Kindly help me.

Comment: @SachinKalia any progress on the issue?